# ng-if on ng-repeat that calls a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-class, angular-ng-if

I have a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/OlLt9XC6cWYnus20ZEaz?p=preview

I have an ng-repeat, that calls a function and gets the result of .outcome, which and either be true or false. However, if these values are not returned, the default is x.

What i want to try to do is perform an ng-if on the ng-repeat value so that:

```
if outcome is true, show icon-true.
if outcome is false, show icon-cross.
if outcome is x, show icon-blank.
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months">
    {[{getData(contents[item._id].contentHistory,year,month.n)}]}
    <!-- <i class="icon-cross" ng-if="getData(contents[item._id].contentHistory,year,month.n == false"></i>
    <i class="icon-true" ng-if="getData(contents[item._id].contentHistory,year,month.n == true"></i>
    <i class="icon-blank" ng-if="getData(contents[item._id].contentHistory,year,month.n == x"></i> -->
</div>
```

Comment: what is `x`?  Is it a string?

Comment: @mgilson yes it is.. take a look at the controller in the plunker

Comment: You need to compare with `'x'` and NOT `x` as its not a variable but a value. And close the round braces to the `getData`call. If thats corrected, the code works fine. Theres something wrong with your styles/icons, I didnt go in that deep, tried using labels instead of icons. worked.

Answer (score 3):

If you need only 2 results - true, false
then you should use `ng-hide` or `ng-show`

else use `ng-switch`

```
<ANY ng-switch="CALL YOUR EXPRESSION">
  <ANY ng-switch-when=true> INSERT TRUE-ICON CODE HERE</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-when=false> INSERT FALSE-ICON CODE HERE</ANY>
  <ANY ng-switch-default>INSERT DEFAULT-ICON CODE HERE</ANY>
</ANY
```

This way, the function gets called only once.

**PS: Your logic works fine, (even though you should not be calling getData 3 times). Get rid of the errors I mentioned in the comment. I tried using labels in place of icons, it works.**

Comment: do you have a working example? I cant seem to get the switch to work.

Comment: Don't copy and paste code from the angular site its not constrcutive enough given ive provided a plunker which highly indicates ive already consulted with the angular docs.

Comment: Sorry, but your plunker had a lots of mistakes which suggested you have NOT consulted the angular docs. You need to compare with `'x'` and NOT `x` as its not a variable but a value. And close the round braces to the getData call. If thats corrected, the code works fine. Theres something wrong with your icons, I didnt go in that deep, tried using labels instead of icons. worked.

Answer (score 1):

try this. define a outcome variable and init it in function.

```
  $scope.outcome = "";
  $scope.getData = function(parameters){
    if(true)
       $scope.outcome = 'show icon-true';
    if(false)
        $scope.outcome = 'show icon-cross';

    }



<div ng-repeat="month in months">
    <i ng-class="{'show icon-true': outcome == true, 'show icon-cross':outcome == false,}"></i>
</div>
```

i put another solution for your problem.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
    $scope.items = [
       {"name":"Ali","class":"a"},
       {"name":"Reza","class":"b"},
       {"name":"Majid","class":"c"}
     ];
  
  $scope.getData = function(param){
     if(param == 'a')
       return 'a';
     if(param == 'b')
       return 'b';
    
    }
    
    
  });
```

```css
.a{
  color:red;
  }
.b{
  color:blue;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   
      <div ng-repeat="item in items">
        
        <p ng-class = "getData(item.class)">{{item.name}}</p>
       </div> 
 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, where has :outcome come from? I am using {[{getData(contents[item._id].contentHistory,year,month.n)}]} to get my outcome.

Comment: @shershen you're correct, that is not ng-class syntax.

Comment: @hadiJZ - the downvote was before your update plus you have not said where outcome has come from

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months">
    <i ng-class="{getData(contents[item._id].contentHistory,year,month.n)==true ?'show icon-true': getData(contents[item._id].contentHistory,year,month.n)==false?'show icon-cross':'show icon-blank'}"></i>
</div>
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: this completely leaves out the third option mentioned by op, hence this solution missed the topic in the first place

Comment: @PatrickKelleter I have updated my answer accordingly. Please check now.

Comment: that's better because it fits the question now, yet it is less performant because it has to call the function twice. but at least its a correct answer now, even if its not best :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but call the function 3 times is highly inefficient

Comment: This always defaults to show-blank - have your tested this??

Answer (score 0):

You can use ternary operator to check for all three conditions by nesting it .

```
<div ng-repeat="month in months">
<i ng-class="{getData(contents[item._id].contentHistory,year,month.n)==true ?'show icon-true': (getData(contents[item._id].contentHistory,year,month.n)==false ? 'show icon-cross' : 'show icon-blank')}"></i>
```